# How can I add search box in single.php?

Tags: search, genesis-theme-framework

I'm using the following code to add a search box in `single.php`:

```
echo '<div class="search-cat-form-left">';
twentythirteen_paging_nav(); 
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="search-cat-form-left">';
twentythirteen_post_nav(); 
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="search-cat-form-right">';
get_search_form(); 
echo '</div>';
```

Here the search box appears, but the search is not working. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this and change the classes if needed.

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></button>
        <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</div><!-- #navbar -->
```